# Spring data jpa limit result with specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have some trouble with Spring data JPA (with hibernate).
I'm using it with a code like this one :

```
Pageable limit = new PageRequest(0, 200);
Specification mySpecification = Specification.where(...);
Page<MyEntite> listEntite = myRepository.findAll(mySpecification, limit);
```

My results are limited to 200 but when i'm looking at the generated query, the limitation is not on the generated SQL.

I need to have the limitation on the generated SQL query to avoid memory errors.

It looks like, the query retrieve all the datas and the filtering is done by spring-data

Comment: I think that you just dont see it in your sql preview or you just looking at  wrong place. Obviously not whole result set will be fetched as whole pagination would be pointles then.

Comment: It looks like, the query retrieve all the datas and the filtering is done by spring-data

Comment: *It looks like,* What makes you think that? 

Again, what did you use to see actual SQL? It is possible that what you see is different query and proper one is somewhere in logs (i know logs can be full of crap)

Comment: I found the query on logs (logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=trace)

Comment: Use p6spy to see real SQL and verify there. Besides you didn't even share log that is bothering you.

Comment: I am not allow to share logs, but i will try with p6spy

Comment: But are you shure that hibernate is not able to show the correct logs of what it will execute ?

Comment: Im not sure of anything as you share no actual data - all you have provided is a story and assumption that cannot be verified in any way.